# iOS Safari Buttons Not Perfect Circles

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I have a basic nav for a carousel, using a `ul`, `li`'s and `buttons`.  You can see a basic version of what I'm talking about here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bootsified/2he1px5c/

In all browsers but iOS Safari, the buttons appear as perfect circles.  In iOS Safari, though, they appear as ovals.  Here are screenshots of what I'm talking about:

http://boots.media/assets/img/dots-screenshot.png

I've tweaked all I can think of, but the only way I can get iOS Safari to make perfect circles is to use "magic numbers" and browser detection.  It's so basic, I can't imagine what is wrong. Any ideas out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't have an iPhone here, nor indeed any device that can run Safari, so I can't tell you with any certainty if this is going to work.

However, I noticed that on my computer, the circles weren't round either. And a bit of experimenting found that when the font size was not 16px, the shape was off.

I updated the fiddle with a font-size for the body, so you can see for yourself. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/2he1px5c/3/).

Turned out the problem was the padding of the button. Apparently, it has a default padding in pixels, which is not the same horizontally and vertically, so if you just add

```css
padding:0;
```

(or any value that *is* the same horizontally and vertically) to the CSS, the buttons are always round, no matter the font size.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
}
button {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: -999em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><button type="button" role="none">1</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" role="none">2</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" role="none">3</button></li>
  <li><button type="button" role="none">4</button></li>
</ul>
```

But again, I can't test on Safari here, so this may not be the solution for you. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Well, crap.  I never thought to remove padding from the button.  So simple...  Can't believe I missed it.  I guess I assumed that was taken care of in my CSS reset.  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: the padding: 0; save me ;) thx